# Linker Error when adding .h file in main.cpp file

Tags: linker, c++14, linker-errors

I have been reading some articles where they seperate the class delceration in .h and defenition in .cpp file and only the .h file is include in main.cpp file. One similar article is here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/header-files-cpp?view=msvc-170
I have tried the following.

**classheader.h file**

```
#ifndef CLASSHEADER_H
#define CLASSHEADER_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class animal{
public:
void set_animal_prop(string a, string b,  int c);
void get_animal_prop();
private:
string name;
string food;
int age;
};
#endif
```

**classheader.cpp file**

```
#include "classheader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void animal::set_animal_prop(string a, string b,  int c)
{
name = a;
food = b;
age = c;
}

void animal::get_animal_prop()
{
cout <<"The animal is : " << name <<endl;
cout <<"It eats : " << food <<endl ;
cout << "Its age is : " << age <<endl; 
}
```

**And main.cpp file**

```
#include "classheader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main () 
{
animal cat;
cat.set_animal_prop("Tom", "Mouse", 7);
animal horse;
horse.set_animal_prop("Max", "Grass", 18);

cat.get_animal_prop();
horse.get_animal_prop();
return 0;
}
```

However when i try to compile the main.cpp file it throws following error.

```
undefined reference to `animal::set_animal_prop(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)'
```

I wanted to know that
How can we get the definitions defined in classheader.cpp file by just including the classheader.h file. Is it even possible?
P.s -when i include classheader.cpp file in my main.cpp file, my program works fine. However the article that i mentioned shows example that only including the .h file is required.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When separating the class declaration in .h file and class definition in .cpp file,
only the .h file is included in both class.cpp and main.cpp file.

Before execution, class.cpp and main.cpp both needs to be compiled and linked together.

Below example clears it.

Put Class decleration in classheader.h file and put class definition in classheader.cpp file. Put the main function in  main.cpp file
classheader.cpp will include "classheader.h" and
main.cpp will also include "classheader.h"

Compilation:

1. Compile classheader.cpp file (classheader.o file will be generated)
   **g++ -c myclass.cpp**
2. compile main.cpp file (main.o file will be generated)
   **g++ -c main.cpp**
3. Link classheader.o and main.o file (on linux => a.out file will be generated / on windows => a.exe file will be generated)
   **g++ classheader.o main.o**
4. Execute the program
   Linux => **./a.out**
   Windows => **./a.exe**